# lossless video to h.265 - [error]: main10 profile not compatible with i422 input chroma subsampling

Tags: ffmpeg, h.265

I have a lossless `.mov` video and I'm trying to encode using h.265 for firetv and some other android tv devices. The spec that they support is:

Based on their native H.265 support, I'm trying to export a `Main 10 Profile with level 4.1`.

The command I'm running is:

```
ffmpeg -i 001_lossless.mov -c:v libx265 -preset slow -profile:v main10 -level:v 4.1 -c:a aac -b:a 128k output.mp4
```

Which yields the following error:

```
x265 [error]: main10 profile not compatible with i422 input chroma subsampling.
```

What is the best way to work around this? I can request the lossless video in different formats also, but I'm not exactly sure what to ask for.

Comment: Show the complete log from the command.

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to add an additional parameter: `-pix_fmt yuv420p`